# Getting System.NotSupportedException when running WCF Service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have created a WCF service using Visual Studio 2010. When i try to run the service, i get the following error

> File name: 'file:///H:\Personal\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WPFBrowser\DatabaseService\bin\Debug\DatabaseService.dll'
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an
>   assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly
>   to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This
>   release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default,
>   so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox
>   the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.LoadServiceAssembly(String
>   svcAssemblyPath)

I even tried setting

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

in the app.config file, but the problem remains.

Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my solution from the network drive to the local C:\ and it started working fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the: "file:///H:\Personal\Visu...". Why the file://? The WCF service should be hosted in the "developer iis" included in Visual Studio. This should result in something like: "http://localhost/abc..."